# Orion Context Broker - Push array element in entities

Tags: arrays, push, entities, fiware-orion

I made entity

> {
>      "contextElements": [
>          {
>              "type": "T1",
>              "isPattern": "false",
>              "id": "E1",
>              "attributes": [
>              {
>                  "name": "A",
>                  "type": "T",
>                  "value": [ "22" , 
>                             {
>                                "x": [ "x1", "x2"], 
>                                "y": "3" 
>                             }, 
>                             [ "z1", "z2" ] 
>                           ]
>              },
>              {
>                  "name": "B",
>                  "type": "T",
>                  "value": {
>                     "x": { 
>                             "x1": "a", 
>                             "x2": "b" 
>                     },
>                     "y": [ "y1", "y2" ]
>                  }
>              }
>              ]
>          }
>      ],
>      "updateAction": "APPEND"
>    }

Now I want to add values in an array, a string ("NEW VALUE") and a json object ({"NEW":"OBJECT"})

> {
>      "contextElements": [
>          {
>              "type": "T1",
>              "isPattern": "false",
>              "id": "E1",
>              "attributes": [
>              {
>                  "name": "A",
>                  "type": "T",
>                  "value": [ "22" , 
>                             {
>                                "x": [ "x1", "x2"], 
>                                "y": "3" 
>                             }, 
>                             [ "z1", "z2" ] ,
>               "NEW VALUE",
>               {"NEW":"OBJECT"}
>                           ]
>              }
>              ]
>          }
>      ],
>      "updateAction": "UPDATE"
>    }

Is possible to add new values as you would do this in array.push()?

Save the previous values and add only new ones after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the present moment (Orion 0.18.1), the only way of adding adding an element to an attribute which value is a vector is to update such attribute with a new vector containing the new element.

However, I think that pushing elements in attributes which value is a vector whitout needing to update the whole vector is an interesting feature to take into account, so we have created [an issue about it](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/744) and eventually it may be implemented.

**EDIT:** this feature was finally implemented in Orion 3.3.0, using the `$push` update operator. For instance, to add item 3 to array attribute A in entity E:

```
PUT /v2/entities/E/attrs/A
{
  "value": { "$push": 3 },
  "type": "Number"
}
```

Full information can be found in [Orion documentation](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/update_operators/index.html).

**EDIT2:** starting in Orion 3.5.0 you can add several items in the same operation using the `$each` modifier. For instance, to add items 3, 4 and 5 to array attribute A in entity E:

```
POST /v2/entities/E/attrs/A
{
  "value": { "$push": {"$each": [3, 4, 5]} },
  "type": "Number"
}
```

(Orion 3.5.0 is not yet released at the present moment, although the fix is already merged in master branch and can be got in `telefonicaiot/fiware-orion:latest` dockerhub image)

Comment: To all who need it in the meantime, can use my idea for solving this problem [link](https://github.com/inter-coder/Orion-Web-Proxy-for-Cross-Domain)

Comment: Answer has been edited to add new information, regarding the implementation of this feature in recent Orion 3.3.0 release.

Comment: New information added to the answer. See EDIT2